# Prevent multiple window And close Window when lost focus JAVAFX

Tags: events, javafx, window, project

I am building a javafx application in which i have a button to change password, for this upon action i want a new Change-password FXML to load . its simple i know but my problem is on every button click a new Change-password window is opening. or is there a way to close Change-password window when it looses focus i.e if i click anywhere else.

```
@FXML
private void CPassBtn(ActionEvent event) {

  try 
    {
        Parent part = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/EmpSalary/ui/Mainwin/forChangePass.fxml"));
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image("/resources/letter.png"));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(part));

        stage.setTitle("Password change");
        stage.show();

    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoginuiController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them. related: you need a model layer that has a boolean property whether or not it is allowed to open the changeDialog, then bind the button's disabled to that property

Comment: thank you for correcting me , i will surely follow java naming conventions from now on .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution check when the focus is changed  and closes if the stage looses focus

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button button = new Button("Password Window");

        Scene scene = new Scene(button);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        button.setOnAction(event -> System.out.println(openPasswordWindow()));
    }

    private String openPasswordWindow(){
        PasswordField passwordField = new PasswordField();
        Stage stage = new Stage(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(passwordField));
        stage.show();

        //You would need from here 
        stage.focusedProperty().addListener((ov, onHidden, onShown) -> {
            if(!stage.isFocused())
                Platform.runLater(() -> stage.close());
        });
        //Down to here

        return passwordField.getText();
    }
}
```

In your code it would look like this

```
@FXML
private void CPassBtn(ActionEvent event) {

    try
    {
        Parent part = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/EmpSalary/ui/Mainwin/forChangePass.fxml"));
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image("/resources/letter.png"));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(part));

        stage.setTitle("Password change");
        stage.show();

        stage.focusedProperty().addListener((ov, onHidden, onShown) -> {
            if(!stage.isFocused())
                Platform.runLater(() -> stage.close());
        });
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoginuiController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much . and all others too , am new at this sorry if i did any mistake in my code , first time using javafx .

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the functionality you described but probably using modality would work (it prevents input events to be handled on the owner or the application depending on the modality):

```
stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
stage.initOwner(((Node) event.getSouce()).getScene().getWindow());
stage.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can prevent multiple windows with a boolean to check if is loaded or not

```
    private boolean stageLoaded = false ;


  @FXML private void CPassBtn(ActionEvent event) {

   try 
{ 
    if(stageLoaded){ return;}
    Parent part = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/EmpSalary/ui/Mainwin/forChangePass.fxml"));
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image("/resources/letter.png"));
    stage.setScene(new Scene(part));

    stage.setTitle("Password change");
    stage.show();

    stageLoaded = true ;
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(LoginuiController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
}
```

but if you need to set stageLoaded = false again . you need to add an event stage.setOnCloseRequest

```
private boolean stageLoaded = false ;


   @FXML private void CPassBtn(ActionEvent event) {

   try 
{ 
if(stageLoaded){ return;}
Parent part =FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/EmpSalary/ui/Mainwin/forChangePa 
ss.fxml"));
Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.setResizable(false);
stage.getIcons().add(new Image("/resources/letter.png"));
stage.setScene(new Scene(part));

stage.setTitle("Password change");
stage.show();

stageLoaded = true ;
 stage.setOnCloseRequest((WindowEvent even) -> {
                stageLoaded = false;

}
 catch (IOException ex) {
Logger.getLogger(LoginuiController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
 null, ex);
 }
 }
```

Comment: can you tell me what i did wrong , please . specifically in my answer . i don't know about "unconventional naming " . thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this is exactly what you are looking for

```
stage.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
{
  @Override
  public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> b, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue)
  {
    if(newValue == false)
        stage.close();
  }
});
```